# Stream min not working sometimes returning max value instead of min

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class GetMiles {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setFee("12000");
        studentList.add(s);
        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setFee("3000");
        studentList.add(s1);
        Optional<Student> optionalStudent = 
    studentList.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Student::getFee));
        if (optionalStudent.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println(optionalStudent.get().getFee());
        }
    }
static class Student {
        private String fee;
        public String getFee() {
            return this.fee;
        }
        public void setFee(String fee) {
            this.fee = fee;
        }
    }
   }
```

in above example it should return 3000 but returning 12000 if we will give 2000 and 3000 it will return 2000 also in most of the scenario its working fine but not for all.

Comment: you are using a String. Change `fee` into a `Number`, like `Double`

Comment: That's because you're getting the min value of String which is comparing values alphabetically.

Comment: You are comparing strings. It comparing by the alphabetic rules, therefore "12000" is less than "3000" ("1" less than "3")

Comment: Yes it seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse map to int in your list and then get min of fee like below example code :

```
Optional<Integer> optionalVal = studentList.stream().map(l -> 
Integer.parseInt(l.getFee())).min(Comparator.comparingInt(k -> k));
if(optionalVal.isPresent()) {
String minFee = String.valueOf(optionalVal.get());
   Optional<Student> studentObj = studentList.stream().filter(p -> 
   minFee.equals(p.getFee())).findFirst();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you compare it with `String`.
Change `fee` to `Integer` or `Long` type.

Comment: so you need to convert string to int, as @Leviand wrote.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using a String, but as you specified , it's a requirement.
So you must change the stream in this way:

```
OptionalInt min = studentList.stream()
    .map(Student::getFee)
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .min();
```

In this way you are casting your String to Int, and then you are taking the min value.

If your value has a decimal , use `mapToDouble` instead

Comment: you cannot pass a `Student` to `Integer::parseInt`. This will not work.

Comment: @f1sh I've typed that on the fly, thanks, I've fixed it

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing on a `String` instead of an `Integer`.

You can fix that by providing a `Comparator` that parses the `String` to an `Integer` (or `double` if you prefer) :

```
Optional<Student> opt = studentList
    .stream()
    .min(Comparator.comparing(stud -> Integer.parseInt(stud.getFee())));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `String` values, you should be comparing numeric values to get expected results, like `doubles` or `ints`. Change the type of your `fee` field to `Double`, `Long`, or `Integer`.

Strings are compared letter by letter, so comparing `3000` and `12000` makes `3000` appear larger, because on the first letter comparison `3` > `1`.